# MySQL: Getting multiple rows based on the value of one row

Tags: mysql, gravity-forms-plugin

My MySQL table looks like the following:

[image]

I would like to get results where all the followings are satisfied:

- `form_id` is 1
- sort by `lead_id` high to low
- `field_number` 9 for that `lead_id` must be 111

In summary, my query should return 9 rows. Is that possible?

Here is my attempt so far, but I really want to avoid using `GROUP_CONCAT` if at all possible to get a cleaner result set.

```
SELECT lead_id, GROUP_CONCAT(field_number, "|", value SEPARATOR "----") AS `values`
FROM lead_detail
WHERE form_id = 1
GROUP BY lead_id
ORDER BY lead_id DESC
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "`field_number` 9 for that `lead_id` must be 111"?

Comment: Ahhh.... the *joys* of working with the EAV model using SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are meaning that you want to *include* only rows for a lead_id if there exists a row for that `lead_id` with `field_number=9` and `value=111`. And otherwise, all rows for that `lead_id` should be excluded...

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT d.id
     , d.lead_id
     , d.form_id
     , d.field_number
     , d.value
  FROM ( SELECT e.lead_id
           FROM lead_detail e
          WHERE e.form_id      = 1
            AND e.field_number = 9
            AND e.value        = 111
          GROUP BY e.lead_id
       ) f
  JOIN lead_detail d
    ON d.lead_id = f.lead_id
   AND d.form_id = 1
 ORDER BY d.lead_id DESC
```

The inline view (aliased as `f`) returns a distinct list of `lead_id` that meet specific criteria.  We can reference the result from that like it were a table, and use that in a `JOIN` operation, to return "matching" rows from the `lead_detail` table. (If there's no row with `value=111`, `field_number=9`, and `form_id=1` for a particular `lead_id`, then the inline view won't return that `lead_id` in the list.)

---

As another alternative, we could use an `EXISTS` predicate with a correlated subquery, but this may not perform as well:

```
SELECT d.id
     , d.lead_id
     , d.form_id
     , d.field_number
     , d.value
  FROM lead_detail d
 WHERE d.form_id = 1
   AND EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM lead_detail e
          WHERE e.form_id      = 1
            AND e.field_number = 9
            AND e.value        = 111
            AND e.lead_id      = d.lead_id
       )
 ORDER BY d.lead_id DESC
```

That essentially says, for every row from `lead_detail` run the subquery following the EXIST keyword... if the subquery returns one (or more) rows, then the EXISTS predicate returns TRUE, otherwise it returns FALSE. That subquery is "correlated" to the outer query, by a predicate in the WHERE clause, matching the `lead_id` to the value of `lead_id` from the row from the outer query.

Comment: the subqueries are missing the "e" alias.

Comment: @farjam: Yes, my bad. The alias assignment is indeed missing from the inline view query and the exists subquery. I will correct that. Thanks! I gave examples of only two query patterns, there are other patterns that would work as well, for example a `d.lead_id IN (subquery)` in place of the EXISTS,

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "not easily."  There are a couple of ways to do this that aren't super straightforward -- probably the easiest is with a sub-query (the exact format will change depending on the exact format of your table, etc.)

```
SELECT lead_id, GROUP_CONCAT(field_number, "|", value SEPARATOR "----") AS `values`
FROM lead_detail
WHERE `form_id` = 1
AND `lead_id` = (SELECT `lead_id` FROM `lead_detail` WHERE `field_number` = 9 AND `value` = 111 AND `form_id` = 1) /*This is the subquery*/
GROUP BY lead_id
ORDER BY lead_id DESC
```

Other options include running two separate queries, one to pull the `form_id` (or `form_ids`) in question, the other to pull all data for that `form_id` (or those `form_ids`).

Comment: I get the following error after running your query: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: @farjam: The behavior you observe is expected. The quickest fix would be to replace the "**`=`**" before the subquery with "**`IN`**".